# Booting from Windows 8 USB, grub unknown filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, grub

So, I've been trying to install Windows 8 along with Ubuntu, so I've got the ISO but whenever I try to boot the Windows installation though the USB I get the "unknown filesystem", which doesn't let me install anything.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Whenever you are trying to boot what?  Ubuntu is already installed and you are trying to install Windows 8?  Are you using EFI booting?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is already installed. I'm trying to install Windows 8. And no, I've been looking about that, couldn't find anything that could help me with it.

Comment: (I also fixed the post, when I'm trying to boot the Windows installation though the USB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use GParted within Ubuntu to shrink your Linux partition so that you have unallocated space available for a new Windows partition
2. Boot from the Windows 8 DVD and install into that unallocated space
3. Boot from a Ubuntu or dedicated Boot Repair LiveCD and run **Boot Repair** as mentioned [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Now *I think* I fixed the unknown filesystem, whatever, now I get a bootmgr image is corrupt. The system cannot boot.

Comment: How did you "fix" it? When are you getting this message - after installing Win8? Also, which OS did your PC originally come with?

Comment: Well, instead of moving the ISO files from the ISO itself to the USB, I used WinUSB. And no, I get this error when trying to install Windows 8. When I tell the computer to boot using the USB device it says that "bootmgr image is corrupt". The computer came with no OS, as I built it from scratch.

Comment: In your BIOS/UEFI settings you may need to disable Secure Boot. For Win8 to USB try [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) or [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/) instead.

Comment: Well, I started getting the "unknown filesystem" again. (And I didn't touch anything). This is really a pain.

Comment: Did you do step 1 first?

Comment: And also, I'm on Ubuntu right now. And seems like those programs only works under Windows.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7569/discussion-between-blastcore-and-karan)

Comment: For some reason WinToFlash crashes on Wine.

Comment: So well, still the bootmgr issue. :(

Comment: I just think WinUSB might be failing here. One of the alternatives I mentioned earlier might be in order now to get WIn8 Setup up and running. A final nuclear option would be to move your important data off the drive to an external using a Linux LiveCD, then using GParted from the same LiveCD to completely wipe the drive clean. After that there's no way a properly created Win8 Setup USB/DVD wouldn't boot.

Comment: Well, it actually was ISO fault, re-downloaded it.